# Very weird issue with npm

Tags: node.js, laravel, vue.js, npm

Hi I do not know what it's happening but I run the command:

```
npm run watch
```

and it displays

```
 /public/js/app.js  1.94 MiB  /public/js/app  [emitted]  /public/js/app
          0.js  40.4 KiB               0  [emitted]
          1.js   690 KiB               1  [emitted]
         10.js  47.6 KiB              10  [emitted]
        100.js  31.2 KiB             100  [emitted]
        101.js  26.6 KiB             101  [emitted]
        102.js  15.4 KiB             102  [emitted]
        103.js  15.8 KiB             103  [emitted]
        104.js    30 KiB             104  [emitted]
        105.js  23.6 KiB             105  [emitted]
        106.js  17.8 KiB             106  [emitted]
        107.js  19.3 KiB             107  [emitted]
        108.js  64.6 KiB             108  [emitted]
        109.js  21.4 KiB             109  [emitted]
         11.js  44.7 KiB              11  [emitted]
        110.js  7.95 KiB             110  [emitted]
        111.js    21 KiB             111  [emitted]
         12.js  44.5 KiB              12  [emitted]
         13.js  32.7 KiB              13  [emitted]
         14.js  44.7 KiB              14  [emitted]
         15.js    47 KiB              15  [emitted]
         16.js  29.9 KiB              16  [emitted]
         17.js  57.1 KiB              17  [emitted]
         18.js  37.8 KiB              18  [emitted]
         19.js  40.6 KiB              19  [emitted]
          2.js  29.1 KiB               2  [emitted]
         20.js  53.6 KiB              20  [emitted]
         21.js  30.6 KiB              21  [emitted]
         22.js  46.9 KiB              22  [emitted]
         23.js  44.5 KiB              23  [emitted]
         24.js  30.5 KiB              24  [emitted]
         25.js  42.7 KiB              25  [emitted]
         26.js  28.6 KiB              26  [emitted]
         27.js  37.7 KiB              27  [emitted]
         28.js  41.1 KiB              28  [emitted]
         29.js  74.1 KiB              29  [emitted]
          3.js  45.6 KiB               3  [emitted]
         30.js  39.5 KiB              30  [emitted]
         31.js  57.2 KiB              31  [emitted]
         32.js  28.6 KiB              32  [emitted]
         33.js  31.7 KiB              33  [emitted]
         34.js  30.7 KiB              34  [emitted]
         35.js    39 KiB              35  [emitted]
         36.js  28.2 KiB              36  [emitted]
         37.js    62 KiB              37  [emitted]
         38.js  30.1 KiB              38  [emitted]
         39.js  47.8 KiB              39  [emitted]
          4.js  72.7 KiB               4  [emitted]
         40.js  36.3 KiB              40  [emitted]
         41.js  41.7 KiB              41  [emitted]
         42.js  35.7 KiB              42  [emitted]
         43.js    40 KiB              43  [emitted]
         44.js  62.2 KiB              44  [emitted]
         45.js  29.2 KiB              45  [emitted]
         46.js  45.5 KiB              46  [emitted]
         47.js  35.5 KiB              47  [emitted]
         48.js  30.9 KiB              48  [emitted]
         49.js    45 KiB              49  [emitted]
          5.js    61 KiB               5  [emitted]
         50.js  35.2 KiB              50  [emitted]
         51.js  37.9 KiB              51  [emitted]
         52.js  30.3 KiB              52  [emitted]
         53.js  57.1 KiB              53  [emitted]
         54.js  39.1 KiB              54  [emitted]
         55.js  41.9 KiB              55  [emitted]
         56.js  23.2 KiB              56  [emitted]
         57.js  29.9 KiB              57  [emitted]
         58.js  24.9 KiB              58  [emitted]
         59.js  25.2 KiB              59  [emitted]
          6.js    65 KiB               6  [emitted]
         60.js    39 KiB              60  [emitted]
         61.js    41 KiB              61  [emitted]
         62.js  35.4 KiB              62  [emitted]
         63.js  49.5 KiB              63  [emitted]
         64.js  72.9 KiB              64  [emitted]
         65.js  57.1 KiB              65  [emitted]
         66.js  60.7 KiB              66  [emitted]
         67.js  39.4 KiB              67  [emitted]
         68.js  29.9 KiB              68  [emitted]
         69.js  72.7 KiB              69  [emitted]
          7.js  62.4 KiB               7  [emitted]
         70.js  53.4 KiB              70  [emitted]
         71.js  50.9 KiB              71  [emitted]
         72.js  79.2 KiB              72  [emitted]
         73.js  38.8 KiB              73  [emitted]
         74.js  56.6 KiB              74  [emitted]
         75.js  50.6 KiB              75  [emitted]
         76.js    68 KiB              76  [emitted]
         77.js    34 KiB              77  [emitted]
         78.js  45.9 KiB              78  [emitted]
         79.js  37.9 KiB              79  [emitted]
          8.js  77.1 KiB               8  [emitted]
         80.js    32 KiB              80  [emitted]
         81.js  40.3 KiB              81  [emitted]
         82.js  56.6 KiB              82  [emitted]
         83.js  50.3 KiB              83  [emitted]
         84.js    45 KiB              84  [emitted]
         85.js    48 KiB              85  [emitted]
         86.js  42.6 KiB              86  [emitted]
         87.js  62.4 KiB              87  [emitted]
         88.js  29.4 KiB              88  [emitted]
         89.js  29.3 KiB              89  [emitted]
          9.js  73.3 KiB               9  [emitted]
         90.js  49.5 KiB              90  [emitted]
         91.js    20 KiB              91  [emitted]
         92.js   8.3 KiB              92  [emitted]
         93.js  8.09 KiB              93  [emitted]
         94.js  35.9 KiB              94  [emitted]
         95.js  30.6 KiB              95  [emitted]
         96.js  28.7 KiB              96  [emitted]
         97.js  40.2 KiB              97  [emitted]
         98.js  17.6 KiB              98  [emitted]
         99.js  14.3 KiB              99  [emitted]
 public/css/app.css   193 KiB  /public/js/app  [emitted]  /public/js/app
```

and it is OK but the thing is that I do not why when I compile it and it says Ok it does not compile in public/ because if I go to public_html and I check it displays this:

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mtNp.png)

So it is out of the folder public/ and I wonder why is it happening?

My webpack.mix is like this one:

```
 const mix = require('laravel-mix');

 mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

so I wonder why is it out of public folder if it says that it will compile in public folder?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When running hot or watch, no actual files are generated in the /public directory.  Instead, a mini server is created to serve these files, normally on port 8080.

Until you run npm run production you will see the actual files on the folder.

The mix() helper on the view automatically handles this difference and serves either the files or the ones generated on port 8080

Comment: But when I run 'npm run watch'... I see that any change did  not happened, I mean that it was setting the compiled data inside public/ before but it put compiled data direct to public_html so I wonder why? how can I change to public_html to public? how it was before

Comment: @JesúsRafaelCovaHuerta You're thinking of `npm run build`.

Comment: @JesúsRafaelCovaHuerta.  I suspect you did an npm run build/production before you had the correct paths and it generated those js files.  Try deleting them and running npm run production to see if they are generated again.

Comment: See I delete all data, it looks like this: [Before npm run](https://ibb.co/DQz6bJc) then when I run npm run watch it looks like this [After npm run](https://ibb.co/VqnLyYX) how you can see it sets the compiled file in public_html/ NOT in public/ so when I want to see the changes, there is not any change because it is not in public/

Comment: What version of laravel-mix are you using?

Comment: The version is 5.0.9

Comment: try removing the 'public/js' for only 'js'